# Convert gridview field into Dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, grid, runtime

i need to convert a field in gridview to a dropdownlist,
but i need to do this in codebehind, and I cannot add a templatefield in apsx(but it could be created at run time execution...)
I populate my grid with this code:

```
        foreach (var item in response.Select(x => x.idMatriz).Distinct())
        {
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < colunas; i++)
            {
                dr[i] = response.Where(x => x.Propriedade == dt.Columns[i].ToString() && x.idMatriz == item).Select(x => x.Valor).FirstOrDefault();
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
```

It works but i need this fileds be a dropdown....
any help?

Comment: Why can't you modify the markup?  That would really be the ideal way to do this.  The code you're showing doesn't seem to have anything to do with the UI...

Comment: I cannot add couse my columns are generated based on database, so when  any data are included/updated/deleted, the columns will change...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all you need to do is dynamically create a template field and add it to the gridview.

```
var field = new TemplateField {HeaderText = col.ColumnName}
gridView.Columns.Add(field);
```

After that, on the row created event of the gridview create and wire up the dropdown.

```
    public void DynamicGridView_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            return;
        }

        var grid = sender as GridView;
        if (grid == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < grid.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            var column = grid.Columns[i] as TemplateField;
            if (column == null)
                continue;

            var cell = e.Row.Cells[i];
            var dropdown = new DropDownList();
            cell.Controls.Add(dropdown);
        }
    }
```