# getting command id from drop down list in a grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net

i inserted a drop down list into my grid view from the code behind like it is done here
[Convert gridview field into Dropdownlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21315343/convert-gridview-field-into-dropdownlist)
i need to make command in the row that contains this dropdownlist when its selected index is changed.
please can some one hepl me 
thanks

Comment: Handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, cast `sender` to `DropDownList`, cast it's `NamingContainer` to `GridViewRow`. Now you are all set.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get the `GridViewRow` of a `DropDownList` which was generated dynamically use following approach.

Add the same `SelectedIndexChanged`-event handler to the dropdowns. Handle it, cast `sender` to `DropDownList`, cast it's `NamingContainer` to `GridViewRow`. Now you are all set.

```
protected void DropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList) sender;
    GridViewRow row =  (GridViewRow) ddl.NamingContainer;
    // now you get the reference to the other controls via row.FindControl
}
```